# Accessing React component's static methods inside propTypes is not allowed

Tags: reactjs

I defined a static array that specifies supported types of input fields. I made them static because 1) they never change, and 2) I want to use them in different components.

Here is what I have.

```
Field = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
      type: React.PropTypes.oneOf(Field.types),
    },

    statics: {
        types: ['text', 'url']
    },

    render() { /* ... */ }

}
```

The error I get in the browser console is this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Field is not defined
```

Why does accessing a static field inside `propTypes` not work? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React takes the `statics` property and creates properties on the resulting component class as it's being defined, so they're not yet available at the time that `propTypes` is evaluated. The simplest solution is simply to extract them; you can still put them on the `statics` for other components to use:

```javascript
var fieldTypes= ['text', 'url'];

var Field = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
      type: React.PropTypes.oneOf(fieldTypes),
    },

    statics: {
        types: fieldTypes
    },

    render() { /* ... */ }
});
```